# How to integrate/add phonegap plugins in WP7 (Windows Phone 7)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, phonegap-plugins

I was trying to add scanner and child browser plugins with phonegap for Windows phone. I have downloaded plugins zip from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins.I just have copied the native .cs and .dll files in the projects plugins folder and corresponding .js to www folder.
I tried to call plugins methods like scan() (for Scanner) and showWebPage() (for child browser) using the following two ways:

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(params);

navigator.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(params);
```

but still the plugins are not working. Does I have missed anything? 
Also i have added references to my copied dll files. I think I have to add entry for my plugin in WMAppManifest.xml , But i don't know how to do that. Is there anyone who tell me the complete procedure to integrate the plugins? And also how to add plugin entry in the WMAppManifest.xml file?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on usage instructions here
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner/deploy

Each Apache Cordova/PhoneGap plugin usually contains two parts (as you noticed): .js and .cs

1. For .cs file you just need to add it to your VS project
2. For .js file you need to add it to correct folder (to be a part of VS project), for example to 'www' and THEN add reference to this .js file in your html page (this step seems to be missed in your case).
3. Optional. For some libraries you will also need to add additional dlls, but you can't miss this step since there will be compilation issues.

To troubleshot

1. Try to place a breakpoint to .cs file to see it is called.
2. Try to add console.log('Hey, I'm initialized') to barrcodescanner.js in the following place

   var BarcodeScanner = function() {
   }

and see if this message is showed in VS Output (Ctrl+Alt+O). If not this means you have incorrect reference to barrcodescanner.js in your html page.

PS. No modification of WMAppManifest.xm is required.

Comment: Thanks not completely but to the most, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to get the Barcodescanner to run on WP7 without luck. I can get the iOS example to work -  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner/Example

Should we be able to use the same code in the iOS example in index.html after adding hte DLLs, js and CS files or would we need to make changes to call scan function ?

If I call navigator.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(), error I see in output is "Error:"Unable to get value of the property 'scan': object is null or undefined".

If I call window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(), I see "Error:"Unable to get value of the property 'barcodeScanner': object is null or undefined".

Will keep trying but I also got the camera sample to work and noticed that the post that there's an issue with being able to call the WP7 camera when connected to Zune and wonder if that's related.